# What's this game with a cyberspace aesthetic featured in a youtube clip?

Tags: game-identification

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EieWQSf8U0Q&t=10s) starts with a montage of game clips and I'm trying to figure out what the game is that appears at 10 seconds in. It features a cyberspace aesthetic and it has a first-person perspective with some kind of high-tech glove.  Here are a few clips.  (The eye in the center is not part of the game, it's just part of the clip montage.)

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: The HUD elements are fairly unique.  I've not seen many games use a yellow snowflake or a celtic triangle.  Unfortunately, searching these hasn't given any useful results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *William Shatner's TekWar* (1995), [as you can see in a previous review by the reviewer you linked.](https://youtu.be/5Tnqs2OIM44?t=1325)

Comment: @Joachim Changed the hyperlink to a timestamped one that includes both the map from the first screenshot and the UI elements seen in the second screenshot.

Comment: Wow, I was starting to think this wasn't a real game! Thanks for figuring it out. It looks pretty cool, too bad it apparently sucks.